# Pop the UIViewController in xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to open a UIViewController from a content page  and this code helps me in doing this

```
        UIWindow Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        var cvc = new ScanningPage();
        var navController = new UINavigationController(cvc);

        Window.RootViewController = navController;

        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
```

but I also want a Back button on that Controller Page which navigate me back to that content Page.

```
this.NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
or
this.DismissViewController(true,null);
```

not working in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not creating a new Window and a UINavigationController...

Xamarin.Forms is contained in a single VC in the first Window, so you can obtain that view controller via:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0].RootViewController;
```

So as an example Dependency service that presents and dismisses a VC (either from Forms or the view controller), you can do something like this.

#### Dependency interface:

```
public interface IDynamicVC
{
    void Show();
    void Dismiss();
}
```

#### iOS Dependency implementation

```
public class DynamicVC : IDynamicVC
{
    UIViewController vc;

    public void Show()
    {
        if (vc != null) throw new Exception("DynamicVC already showing");
        vc = new UIViewController();
        var button = new UIButton(new CGRect(100, 100, 200, 200));
        button.SetTitle("Back", UIControlState.Normal);
        button.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        button.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            Dismiss();
        };
        vc.Add(button);
        var rootVC = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0].RootViewController;
        rootVC.PresentViewController(vc, true, () => { });
    }

    public void Dismiss()
    {
        vc?.DismissViewController(true, () =>
        {
            vc.Dispose();
            vc = null;
        });
    }
}
```